# When, if ever, can standard enthalphy be subsituted for standard chemical potiential?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

I'm reading through a combustion modeling paper by Gordon & McBride which is a bit scant on some of the algebra & calculus used to derive their equations. My advisor and I have derived nearly all the equations missing clear derivations except for a few where the chemical potential seems to be have been completely substituted for by standard enthalpy.

We are mathematicians, and we figure this is likely some clever algebraic trick using a chemical equivalence we are unaware of, but which is so well-known to a chemistry audience that the authors did not bother to include the pertinent equation. The only thing I can think of is that somehow the Gibbs definition was used. However, there is no entropy in the final equation, as I would expect if the Gibbs definition were used to substitute for chemical potential.

Do you chemistry folk have any pointers for a lost math fellow?

Comment: No wonder you are lost. I have yet to find a chemist who can *explain* the concept of chemical potential in words. Every textbook regurgitates some circular definition of chemical potential without ever mentioning how it can be practically measured.

Comment: @M.Farooq Come now, that's hardly true that it can't be explained in a non-circular fashion.  It's an intensive property that determines the gradient for the flow of matter -- a substance will naturally flow from a region of higher to lower chemical potential, just as thermal energy will naturally flow from a hot region to a cold region.  And both occur because that process increases the entropy of the universe.   Nor is it true that it can't be measured. Saying you can't measure the chemical potential is tantamount to saying you can't determine the Gibbs free energy, since $\mu$ = G/n.

Comment: You need to provide more detail regarding what sort of process you are modeling. You might be justified to drop the entropic contribution, obviously where the enthalpy change is large in comparison.

Comment: @neph It would help if you could give us a reference to the paper, and reproduce the specific equations that are troubling you.  

Are you referring to the following?: Gordon, Sanford, and Bonnie J. McBride. "Computer Program for Calculation of Complex Chemical Equilibrium Compositions, Rocket Performance, Incident and Reflected Shocks, and Chapman-Jouguet Detonations. Interim Revision, March 1976." (1976).